# Как добавить символ к строке?

Tags: java

Код работает, но если к строке input добавить еще один символ, то выдаст ошибку. Подскажите каким способом можно добавлять n количество символов к строке, чтобы `(input % 4) == 0;`

```java
String input = "325415123546874511223659";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 4) {
   String number = new String(chars, i, 4);
   if (number.length() != 4) {
       chars = Arrays.copyOf(chars, chars.length + 1);
       chars[chars.length - 1] = '0';
   }
   System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

Comment: любой поиск -> "java добавить символы к строке"

Comment: Ну теперь даже еще хуже стало, чем было изначально. Читай ошибку и исправляй.

Comment: @Эникейщик [лучше не надо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а что ещё можно сделать?

Comment: @Зонтик ответить или закрыть дубликатом, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка при добавлении символа к строке `input` связана с выходом за пределы строки при создании  `number`: `String number = new String(chars, i, 4);`

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 24, count 4, length 25
```

то есть, код `if (number.length() != 4)` выполняться не будет.

Однако, если задача в том, чтобы дополнить строку **символами нуля `'0'`**, поддерживая длину строки кратной `n (4)`, следует вычислить нужное число нулей при помощи операции `%`.

```java
public static String addZeros(String input, int n) {
    int zeros = input.length() % n;
    return zeros == 0 ? input : input + "0".repeat(n - zeros);
}
```

Тест:

```java
int n = 4;
String input = addZeros("3254151235468745112236592", n);

char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i += n) {
   String number = new String(chars, i, n);
   System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

Исходная строка из 25 символов дополнена 3 нулями

```
3254 1512 3546 8745 1122 3659 2000
```

Также при работе с изменяемыми строками лучше использовать `StringBuilder / StringBuffer`, а не "низкоуровневое" копирование массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы выходите за границу при создании новой строки. Используйте проверку наподобие:

```
 if (i + 4 >= chars.length) {
     number = new String(chars, i, chars.length - i);
 } else {
     number = new String(chars, i, 4);
 }
```